# How can I log discarded fields when deserializing with GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using JSON as a save format.

If I change the field names of my object GSON will silently discard the original fields upon loading the older version, because they no longer match the new names.

I would like to be able to get some notification if I do this accidentally through refactoring, i.e. "Warning: variableName not found in ObjectType during deserialization."
There is a @Version annotation but it isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

Has anyone written a custom deserializer or custom type converter that will throw an error when a field in the JSON does not exist in the type? Is there another serialization library that does this?

Edit: I would still be interested in a GSON deserializer that does this as well, if anyone has one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) can be used to fail on unexpected JSON elements.  Jackson can also be configured to gather (and log) all unbound JSON elements, as described at http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/09/entry_414.html (search for "any setter").

If you're already familiar with Gson, I documented how to use Jackson to do the same things covered in the Gson User Guide at http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/07/gson-v-jackson-part-6.html.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. I marked this as the solution since it's probably better than using a custom deserializer.

Comment: Does this actually answer the question asked in the title? _"How can I log discarded fields when deserializing with GSON?"_